# Who deletes comments? Is it the tooth fairy?

Tags: discussion, comments

So Who deletes comments?

I keep making insulting comments, but someone keeps deleting them.

### Is it the tooth fairy?

Comment: Yes. And it will be a leprechaun that suspends you for making too many insulting comments.

Comment: @phantom42, as long as it is at the end of a rainbow.

Comment: I don't see what you aim to gain from this? Why do you feel the need to post insulting comments, and do you not feel if someone were to insult you you'd like the comments to be deleted?

Comment: @KyloRen- You're drunk, go home

Comment: @Valorum, how did you know that. I am rather plastered at the moment.

Comment: @KyloRen - Call it a hunch. My advice is to turn delete this question and turn off your computer before you get yourself into real trouble.

Comment: @Valorum, can't delete a question that has an answer. I have vandalized a question and been banned for a while before.

Comment: I flagged that comment. You were complaining about _one_ downvote. I upvoted the question, and flagged the comment as rude.

Answer (score 18):

> There are three ways that a comment can get deleted.
>
> - A user can delete their own comment.
> - A moderator can delete anyone's comments.
> - Any user with at least 15 reputation can flag a comment, and enough flags can cause the deletion of that comment.
>
> <sub>-- [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99818/278659)</sub>

Insulting comments *will* be deleted, whether by a moderator or by sufficient community flags.

As a general note, insulting comments are [against the rules](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and too many of them from a single user may lead to time in the [penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: Ohh, I had my share of the penalty box.

Comment: @KyloRen That's not a good thing.